How can we prevent logging in and out repeatedly when utilizing multiple spec files in a Cypress Test Suite focused on grouping?
I have four test cases that require using the same credentials for logging in. When grouping these test cases, I aim to perform the login process only once, and ensure Cypress does not close the browser afterward.
In package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "groupingspec": "cypress run --spec cypress/integration/specs/OneSpec.js cypress/integration/specs/TwoSpec.js cypress/integration/specs/ThreeSpec.js cypress/integration/specs/FourSpec.js --browser chrome --headed",
  }
}

Run from terminal:
npm run groupingspec


I find cy.session() is quite limiting for handling tests as a group.
Instead I use bahmutov/cypress-data-session plugin which is an enhanced version of the older cy.session command.
The summary comparison between the two:
cy.dataSession vs cy.session



Feature
cy.session
cy.dataSession




Command is
official ✅
community 


Can cache
the browser session state
anything


Stability
production
production


Cache across specs
yes
yes


Access to the cached data
no
yes


Custom validation
no
yes


Custom restore
no
yes


Dependent caching
no
yes


Time limit
no
yes


Use count limit
no
yes


Static utility methods
limited
all


GUI integration
yes
no


Should you use it?
maybe
yes


Cypress version support
newer versions
all



Note the first link in the Github page is broken, it should be
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-data-session/.
These links provide a huge amount out useful examples for starting out.
Note Cypress cy.session() fails login caching when there is a reset of the browser, but cy.dataSession() does not fail because it uses the Node process to handle the cache.
This is the example I use, which logs in via API call
const loginViaApi = (username, password) => {
  cy.log(`log in user **${username}**`)
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/login',
    form: true,
    body: {
      username,
      password,
    },
  })
  // after cy.request, the cookie should exist in the browser
  return cy.getCookie('connect.sid')
}

it('register and log in using data sessions', () => {
  const username = 'Test'
  const password = 'MySecreT'

  cy.dataSession({
    name: 'logged in user',
    setup() {
      return loginViaApi(username, password)
    },
  })

  // if the user is logged in correctly,
  // the session cookie is set, and when we visit the page
  // we are automatically redirected to the list of chat rooms
  cy.visit('/')
  cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/rooms')
})


cy.session() can store your browser context between tests, in this case, the cookies and session/local storage used to identify your user as "logged in". Note: Cypress will still "close the browser" between tests, but using cy.session means that when Cypress opens the new browser, your previous browser state will be restored.
There is an option with cy.session to cache the context across spec files.
